# Jquery Form Validation - Show errors one at a time

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have working code where it shows all errors in the form when clicked on a button. But having all errors at once just mess-up my screen. Is there way to show error one at a time...

```
 $('#bet_cal_form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
        $(element).tooltipster('show');
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('hide');
    },

    rules: {
        odd_a1: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5

        },
        odd_b1: {
            required: true

        }
    },

});
```

Thanks...

Added - Here is sample code I found this in..
http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/

Comment: pls throw me the link of the plugin

Comment: here is link i got the code from..  http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/

Comment: Maybe you we'll need to pull a request on https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/pulls for an extra feature of this plugin

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Tooltipster.  The jQuery Validate plugin will show _all_ pending form errors when you click the submit button because that's how the user expects form validation to work.  If you want to see errors one at a time, then don't click the submit button before filling out the form... that's exactly how it's already working.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the elements with onblur event and check if the element is valid in the onblur method. Note: onblur does not work on radio/select so you will have to also override onchange/onclick events in your validation js file.

Hope that answered your query.